# Как сделать обработку запроса в php и через ajax отдавать обработанный ответ?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Собственно есть форма

```
<form id="formx">
        <legend>Test From</legend>
        <label for="name">Название:</label>
        <input id="name" name="data" value="" type="text">
        <input value="Send" type="submit">
    </form>
```

скрипт который обрабатывает форму

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $('form#formx').on('submit', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var msg   = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'res.php',
              data: msg,
              success: function(data) {
                //в data должен быть ответ сервера в формате JSON
                var response = JSON.parse(data); //массив в котором ваши данные
                var html='<ul>';
                for(var i in response)html+='<li>'+response[i].russian+'</li>';
                html+='</ul>';
                $('#results').html(html);
                  // i - номер объекта, {key} - ваш ключ из массива
              },
              error:  function(xhr, str){
                    alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
                }
            });
      });
    </script>
```

результат после ajax выводится сюда

```
<div id="results">Вывод</div>
```

Сам обработчик файл res.php

```
$array = array();

$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://shikimori.org/api/animes/search?q='.$_POST['data'];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "User Agent");
if ($content = curl_exec($ch)) {
$array = json_decode($content, true);
}
curl_close($ch);

print($content);
```

что надо прописать в javascript выше

```
<div id="results">Вывод</div>
```

чтобы в данный div id вывести ответ, который я хочу прописать в res.php например:

```
вместо print($content);
```

прописать

```
foreach($array as $row) {
  $name = $row["name"];
  $russian = $row["russian"];
  echo "$name // $russian<br>";

}
```

Comment: на первый взгляд `echo $content ;`

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно в чем проблема.

Если есть необходимость формировать результата на стороне сервера, то не нужно парсить JSON на клиенте. И тогда функция `success` сводится к одной строке:

```
 $('#results').html(data);
```

Т.е., что пришло из PHP скрипта, то и вывели в блок.

Либо как вариант можно поменять форматирование на строне клиента. Т.е. будет что-то навроде

```
html+=response[i].name + ' // ' + response[i].russian + '<br />';
```

И убрать использование ul - если список в выводе не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

У вас как минимум 2 не стыковки:

1. Вы на сервере возвращаете HTML, а не JSON;
2. На клиенте зачем то парсите JSON, хотя сервер уже HTML возвращает.

Варианта 2:

1. Либо на сервере генерируйте JSON с помощью
   [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).
2. Либо на стороне клиента просто вставляете через
   [$('#result').html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

PS:

Что бы не было такого костыля:

> //в data должен быть ответ сервера в формате JSON
>
> var response = JSON.parse(data); //массив в котором ваши данные

Надо в [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) передавать в объект настроек нужный тип(`dataType`) ожидаемого контента от сервера:

```
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'res.php',
          dataType: 'json'
          data: msg,
          success: function(data) {}, // data уже js объект
          error:  function(xhr, str){}
        });
```